# How to group into 2 week increments by created_at [ruby]

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activejob

I have survey responses that I need to display in 2 week increments based on the created_at date. The output should be something like:

{10/1 : 4
10/15: 6
10/29: 3}

...where the first week is created from the earliest created_at date in the survey responses and the same for the last, but the latest created_at. I've seen things like `group_by{ |s| s.created_at.month}` but not something for every other week, starting on the Monday of the week. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You might try [groupdate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) and group your data by week.

Answer (score 0):

You could [calculate the number of days](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-2D) between the current record and the [oldest](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-minimum) and then use [modulo 14](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Numeric.html#method-i-modulo):

```
oldest_date = YourModel.minimum(:created_at).to_date
your_relation.group_by { |record| 
  (record.created_at.to_date - oldest_date).modulo(14)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a method returning the year and the week range, for example:

```
def by_year_and_by_two_weeks(my_date)
  wk = my_date.strftime("%W").to_i/2
  wks = [wk, wk.odd? ? wk+1 : wk - 1].sort # <== adjust this
  [my_date.year, wks]
end
```

The `%W` in rails uses monday as the first day of the week.

So, when you have your object:

```
object.created_at #=> 2021-09-19 08:58:16.78053 +0200
by_year_and_by_two_weeks(object.created_at) #=> [2021, [17, 18]]
```

Then you can use the method for grouping.

```
objects.group_by { |d| by_year_and_by_two_weeks(d.created_at) }
```

This is an example of result after values transformation to make it readables:

```
{[2021, [20, 21]]=>[2021-10-14 09:00:17.421142 +0200, 2021-10-15 09:00:17.421224 +0200, 2021-10-06 09:00:17.421276 +0200, 2021-10-10 09:00:17.421328 +0200], [2021, [18, 19]]=>[2021-09-22 09:00:17.421385 +0200]}
```

Of course you can change the `by_year_and_by_two_weeks` return value as it best fits for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements:

- You want to group on the monday of the starting biweekly period.
- You want the **Hash key** of the group to be the date of that monday.

I will also add another future-proofing requirement:

- The start and end dates can be anywhere, even accross year boundaries.

If we take these requirements, and then utilize the `modulo` idea from spickermann, we can build it like this:

```
start_date = first_item.created_at.to_date.prev_occurring(:monday)

your_items.group_by { |item|
  item_date       = item.created_at.to_date
  days_from_start = item_date - start_date
  biweekly_offset = days_from_start.modulo(14)
  biweekly_monday = item_date - biweekly_offset
  biweekly_monday
}
```

Example:

```
test_dates = [
  Date.new(2021, 10, 1),
  Date.new(2021, 10, 6),
  Date.new(2021, 10, 10),
  Date.new(2021, 10, 13),
  Date.new(2021, 10, 20),
  Date.new(2021, 10, 31)
]

start = test_dates.first.prev_occurring(:monday)

pp test_dates.group_by { |date|
  days_from_start = date - start
  biweekly_offset = days_from_start.modulo(14)
  biweekly_monday = date - biweekly_offset
  biweekly_monday
}
```

Output:

```
{ Mon, 27 Sep 2021 => [Fri, 01 Oct 2021, Wed, 06 Oct 2021, Sun, 10 Oct 2021],
  Mon, 11 Oct 2021 => [Wed, 13 Oct 2021, Wed, 20 Oct 2021],
  Mon, 25 Oct 2021 => [Sun, 31 Oct 2021] }
```